# If the Moon was made of cheese, what should we do with it?

Tags: space, moons, food

The Moon is made of cheese. So:

- Should we eat the whole moon or should we keep it until the famine breaks out?
- Will the moon melt or freeze or neither?
- Can you still eat the cheese after a while or will it spoil?
- Is it safe to eat this Moon cheese?
- Would you get high from this Moon cheese, just like spacecake?
- What would happen if the cheese melts because of the sun?

What do you think, what we do with it?

Comment: I think the moon will explode!

Comment: I think you should read [Mole of moles](https://what-if.xkcd.com/4/).

Comment: Depends - blue cheese, mozzarella, or feta?

Comment: The tempature swings, pressure and time will turn it into an unpleasant sludge of organic molecules. see Oil, also organic matter + temperature, pressure and time. If any chemical reactions produce heat then it wont escape until steam geezers erupt.

Comment: We should restart our space program in earnest, then bombard the moon with flour, lard, baking powder, and a little salt, until we have created the galaxy's biggest quesadilla. Humanity need never hunger again.

Answer (score 17):

### What do we do with it?

At least to start with, we'll leave it there. As illustrated in many places around this site, going to space and moving cargo around costs a lot. Given that we do have enough food on the planet (albeit not equally spread), there would not be much value in harvesting Moon cheese.

We'd also have the scientists on our backs telling us not to harvest the Moon because the Moon keeps many things on Earth stable, such as the tides.

### Melt or Freeze?

Both. When the Moon is in line of radiation from the Sun, it'll melt the cheese on one side. When that side turns away it'll freeze again. When the Moon is behind Earth, all the cheese would freeze. It would be a very strange place to visit, to be sure.

### Would it go off?

Nope. Bacteria and fungi are what cause food to go off, but they're lifeforms that exist only on Earth and could not survive in space. However, it would be hard to eat given that it's always either frozen solid or burn-your-tongue-off boiling.

The Moon won't explode as it will still have gravity keeping it together, but its overall mass would be significantly less as the density of cheese is less than that of rock.

Comment: Would lower mass affect our tides?

Comment: @EFrog Yes, but the lower mass would also eventually let the Earth's gravity pull the Moon into lower orbit, where the gravitational effect would return to normal.

Comment: Cheese is made from with bacteria, so there should be bacteria on the moon. Not sure it wouldn't go bad then.

Comment: @Sheraff The Moon has no atmosphere so space would kill off the bacteria

Comment: What about the inside of the moon? Plus, some bacteria can survive in anaerobic environments I believe, some even made it to Mars, hitching a ride on our probes I read somewhere.

Comment: @Sheraff Possibly, but ut's also possible that the cheese is porous enough to allow the cold to penetrate

Comment: I still think the moon would explode and end up with cheese everywhere in space no matter where you go!

Comment: Would there be a long string of semi-melted cheese going from Moon to Earth? Or cheesy rain?

Comment: @Stefan Why you think so?

Comment: @algiogia It's possible but unlikely

Comment: @artofcode Because Cheese.

Comment: @ArtOfCode people would cut off pieces of cheese when it reaches the ground, to avoid it reeling on Earth :)

Comment: @algiogia cheese comet tail? Maybe even cheese dust ring around Earth?

Comment: @PTwr I like the idea of the ring, but not of dust. More something like: @/O

Comment: @algiogia do you mean something like [my cute painting](http://i.imgur.com/NzTKod6.jpg)? Cheese dust tail from moon slowly falling into planet atmosphere? Cheesy aurora?

Comment: @PTwr I was thinking of a cheesy ring, but cheesy aurora is also a good idea!

Comment: Is said Spacecheese poisonous?

Comment: Its worth noting that food can spoil without the action of bacteria/fungi. For example bread can spoil in two ways; it can go mouldy (fungus got there first) or it can go stale (it crystalised - [it isn't actually the loss of water interestingly](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/2013-08-19/what-makes-bread-go-stale-.html)). Bread will go stale in a sterile enviroment. Now, I have no idea what a perpetual freeze boil cycle would do to cheese, but I recon even if you brought it back to room temperature it still wouldn't be quite the same

Comment: @RichardTingle Probably not, but it would at least be edible. Stale bread is still edible though disgusting

Comment: @ArtOfCode "lower mass would also eventually let the Earth's gravity pull the Moon into lower orbit" - really? I might be wrong but I thought the orbital altitude was only related to the lateral speed of the object? Besides, if anything, shouldn't lower mass (therefore less gravity) send it into a higher orbit?

Answer (score 11):

We would start the search for extraterrestrial crackers.

Also, see *[Wallace and Gromit: A Grand Day Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Grand_Day_Out)*.

Comment: Cheese will explode

Comment: Possibly what Wallace and Gramit did in A Grand Day Out they build a rocket as it was Wallace favourite food