# If the moon were actually made of cheese, how long would it take to spoil?

Tags: science-based, moons, food

Let's say that our moon is actually made of cheese, except for the outer layer of rock. Although there are no microbes or oxygen, temperature is still a factor in its spoilage. Is there a formula that links temperature to pressure that could describe how long it would take for the moon to spoil?

Part B: if and when it does, could we tell from Earth?

Comment: The answer to [If the moon was made of cheese what should we do with it?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/if-the-moon-was-made-of-cheese-what-should-we-do-with-it) question might help you with that question.

Comment: Maybe Tα/ρcP? I don't know enough physics to determine whether that would be applicable here.

Comment: @Secespitus I question the validity of those answers.  Even without bacteria, the excessive heat and excessive coldness of the moon combined with the raw radiation would render the cheese inedible rather quickly. It is questionable if the cheese would still be identifiable as cheese after changing composition so much.

Comment: @user2259716 if it is no longer cheese then premise of the questions is false, isn't it? And with questions so wild at need to handwave things that make premise false to answer at all

Comment: The high temperature, pressure and time combine to turn the cheese into goop. At first the cheese will seem to be keeping well but slow chemical reactions release heat that can't escape. After a few million years the result resembles crude oil.

Comment: Compare the density of the moon 3.34 grams per cubic centimeter to cheese, perhaps 1 gram per cubed centimeter (being very generous) it would orbit much lower if it didn't outright crash on Earth, and maybe you could smell that it's spoiled :-)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  The other is an opinion-based question asking what we should do (and IMO is rightly closed); this question asks about spoilage and seems answerable, though we might need details about the thickness and completeness of the rock shell.

Comment: @MonicaCellio How many sites are you an admin on?!

Comment: @DonielF five.  Hi, welcome to Worldbuilding!  I know this isn't your first post here, but I hadn't noticed you before. :-)  (BTW, if you [edit] to add the info I asked about, your question will automatically go to the reopen review queue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space is cold, it can easily be -170 C° Your cheese will not be spoiled for a hell of a long time. Cold boiling is because of a low pressure, however, we're in a celestial body, it has a lower gravitational force, but still. Also, that water isn't alone, it's bound to various other materials too. [Water-containing life can and will survive in space without any special equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade#Physiology), and cheese isn't even alive in the first place.

Cosmic radiation is a factor, but I don't think it can get through the rock easily.

So yes, You can has a cheezburger.

---

The second part is an obvious No, We can only assume, and a yes, we can easily be almost sure, that cheese hasn't got spoiled (entirely).

---

Friendly note: For cold boiling, we need the stuff to have energy, so it would wiggle around enough, low pressure will lower the energy wiggling needed to break free, however in cheese and ice, there's a stronger connection between the atoms, thus will boil if they're given more energy and not just low pressure.

Watch, what happens to  vacuumed flesh:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KjLJiydw6do

Spoiler: *Absolutely nothing.* :)

Hope you enjoyed this little answer.